# What's the top prize tier in Coin Dozer?

Tags: coin-dozer

I've got a couple prize collections at the 3rd or 4th tier (meaning that I have at least 3 or 4 of each prize color) and the next logical goal would be to get to the 6th tier.

When I reached tier one, that single star turned into six stars, indicating that I had more tiers to reach. Does it do the same thing at tier six? What about after that? Is there a prize endgame?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are tiers above 6 now (possibly from a recent update?)  If you get a chance, can you reevaluate this question @authenticgeek?

Comment: @DaveMcClelland I'll take a look later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are up to nine tiers of each bonus. But you have to buy the upgrade from 6 to 9 tiers for each bonus separately for 10 Dozer Dollars each. The Dozer Dollars you can buy for cash or earn in-game by collecting puzzle pieces.

[image: Upgrade screen screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

*This was previously true, but has been modified during more recent updates. It's no longer the correct answer.*

I can confirm that the star counts do not increase beyond six and that there is no "reward unlocked" message for a seventh tier collection, leading me to believe that benefits do not increase beyond tier six.

Comment: That's odd... I only recently installed the game on my iPad and I have several prize collections at tier 9...

Answer (score 2):

There is no answer that sums it up, so here's my two-cents.

The highest tier that you can achieve is nine. You can get these by spending ten Dozer Dollars to upgrade one category from six as the highest tier to nine as the highest tier. You earn Dozer Dollars by either buying them via. iTunes or earn ingame by collecting puzzle pieces to solve puzzles. Solving puzzles awards you a set number of Dozer Dollars (I believe it was twelve per puzzle solved) and some experience (I think it was around 5000).

However, it should also be noted that after a while, the game is self-sustaining. You have more money than you know what to do with, and you start to lose interest in the game.

After you finish the puzzles, the game starts to advertise other games that the company Game Circus created, starting with Horse Frenzy. After completing the puzzle and collecting your prize (Dozer Dollars and Experience), you can scroll the page to see the next puzzle. Therefore, there is no endgame, so long as the company keeps pushing out new games. Additionally, it is possible to have six-digits worth of coins, as well as being up to level 300 (I'm not sure why I continue to play this game :P).

Answer (score 1):

After you get to 20 of each prize another prize appears: "Stuffed puppies".

At some point silver coins are the same size as the red and blue coins. So my conclusion is the game keeps advancing.

Answer (score 1):

There is 7th tier and way more. You just need to complete 2 puzzles to get enough 10 dozer dollars to buy more tiers

Answer (score 1):

if you have ten dozer dollars to spend you can buy an upgrade to nine tiers of bonuses. Example: if you upgrade to nine tiers of bonuses of yoyos, at tiers 7+ there is no regen limit while playing.

Comment: I've had the Whistles at tier 3, and spend 10 dozer-Dollar for upgrade, the 10 DD´s are gone but the Whistles are still at tier 3

Answer (score 0):

I just unlocked what was said to be tier two of six. So I'd assume 6 tiers per prize type.
Though I am unsure if you need to keep prizes once unlocked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've collected 6 of each of everyone the prizes. There is no tier 7. This means you've topped out. Time to move on to another app.

Comment: Exactly: Coin Dozer: Seasons :D

Answer (score 0):

I' have reached the level of 288 has got all the stars in all the awards and Mma After that, you ended up on, any game over

Answer (score 0):

You go for 1, then 6, then 9. I'm trying to get up to 2, but I keep selling them to get something better.And its 5d.d, 1000xp for the first puzzle, 6d.d, 1500xp for the second, 12d.d, 5000xp for the third, and 15d.d, 1000xp for the fourth.

Answer (score -1):

The game advances to max tier of nine stars. I'm on level 240 with 29,008 coins, and another part of the park changes.

Also, on an unrelated note, change the date on your phone one day ahead to get free coins.

Comment: Could you reword your answer? I find it difficult to understand.